# Why is Phryne's hair purple in the Manga, but brown in the Anime?

Tags: fractale

In the Manga, Phryne and Nessa have purple hair.
In the Anime, Phryne has brown hair and Nessa has red hair.

Is there a reason for this inconsistency?

[image][image]

Comment: This really bothered me since I think there's actually a reason they have the same color hair...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No real sources or references for this, but it's almost certainly the work of Masako Tashiro, the anime's character designer. As you can see in a [design comparison image on this page](http://washiblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/fractale-background-and-review/), the detail and color changes between Hidari's and Tashiro's designs. When you have to animate characters, it's up to the character designer to not only create fitting and unique designs that match each character, but make them simple enough so that the animators can animate them in a reasonable amount of time. This is why you rarely see anime TV series with characters of the same gender that have the exact same hair color. Without all of the detail that can be afforded to still frames in a manga, there's often a reliance on colors to easily differentiate between characters that share the screen a lot.

Comment: That's an interesting read. I'll wait a while before I accept an answer to see if anything else comes. (especially after the discussion about recruitment earlier today)